# Fetch content of next td on checkbox click

Tags: javascript

How to fetch the content of the next `td` when the check box is clicked

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type=checkbox name=t>
        </td>
        <td width=25%>
            FOOBAR
        </td>
        <td width=73%>
            BAZ
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type=checkbox name=t>
        </td>
        <td width=25%>
            FOO
        </td>
        <td width=73%>
            BAR
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My javascript code:

```
var c=new Array();
c=window.document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++)
{
    if(c[i].type=='checkbox')
    {
        alert(c[i].parentNode.parentNode.rows[0].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

I am trying to fetch the content of the next td when a check box is clicked. For the first row, `FOOBAR` should be fetched and so on.

**EDIT**

> **POINTS TO NOTE:** I'm pretty sure about the tags that I am using for
>   this question. Please dont post any answers that point to some JS
>   library eg. jQuery etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, though it's *very* HTML-dependant (as is much JavaScript that involves DOM-traversal, of course):

```
var c = [];

c = window.document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    if (c[i].type == 'checkbox') {
        c[i].onchange = function() {
            if (this.checked){
                console.log(this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.firstChild.nodeValue.trim());
            }
        };
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/z88HH/9/).

References:

- [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.firstChild).
- [`nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling).
- [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeValue).
- [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.parentNode).
- [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Comment: Does it work well? I think is not working properly because if you click the same checkbox every time (checked or not checked) you are printing in console (and the purpose is to print when it is just checked). Also, the same value "FOO" is getting printed when clicking "FOOBAR" checkbox, and you never get "FOOBAR" printed. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @OscarJara, yeah, you were right. I messed up when caching the variable `that` and...sigh. Since edited and corrected. Thanks for the pointer, though. I wouldn't have caught it had you not left that comment. XD

Answer (score 0):

I have used jQuery. I am guessing that's alright?

```
    ​$('input:checkbox').live('click', function() {
       alert($(this).parent().next('td').text());
    });​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Mwqz/

Comment: The question isn't tagged with `jQuery`, so I would assume OP *doesn't* want a jQuery solution, but I suppose he'll have to let you know. Also, it should be noted that `.live()` has been deprecated in favor of `.on()`.

Comment: i know how to make it using jquery. but i dont want any overload on my site for such a basic task.

Comment: @OscarJara - I guess i tagged the question well enough. I dont see any jQuery code i put up there?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery, will be better, here your solution:

```
$('[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){
  var html;
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    html = $(this).parent().next('td').html();
    alert(html);
  }
});
​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/yYuzS/

Comment: I think SO community has made options for tags while questioning and I know well how and when to use them. PS- check the question tags.