# Why would a script differ in evaluating 'element.checked' in the same script, acting on different table-rows with the same structure?

Tags: javascript

I wrote an answer to this question: [Fetch content of next td on checkbox click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340258/fetch-content-of-next-td-on-checkbox-click/10340463), the answer was accepted (as of writing this question).

The intent was to find the text-value of the table-cell following the current cell that contained the input checkbox; for the second row this works (in Chrome 18/WinXP), but in the first row the evaluation `console.log(that.checked);` evaluates to false (regardless, so far as I can see, of it being checked or not).

The supplied HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type=checkbox name=t>
        </td>
        <td width=25%>
            FOOBAR
        </td>
        <td width=73%>
            BAZ
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type=checkbox name=t>
        </td>
        <td width=25%>
            FOO
        </td>
        <td width=73%>
            BAR
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
var c = [];

c = window.document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    var that = c[i];
    if (that.type == 'checkbox') {
        that.onchange = function() {
            console.log(that.checked);
            if (that.checked){
                console.log(that.parentNode.nextElementSibling.firstChild.nodeValue.trim());
            }
        };
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/z88HH/2/).

Note that it *seems* to work reliably for the second row (and logs `FOO` to the console), but in the first row the console logs only `false`. Is there an obvious mistake I'm making?

Comment: You're getting your this and that confused.

Comment: Always the way; there are times we should just know to stop. Or take a bit of a break. Oops. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually running into an issue unrelated to `checked`. Your `that` variable is outside the scope of the event handler, and so it is always resolving to `c[1]`. You need to either wrap the thing in a closure (aka `function () { ... }();`  or just change `that` to `this` inside your event handler, like in this: http://jsfiddle.net/z88HH/3/

```
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    var that = c[i];
    if (that.type == 'checkbox') {
        that.onchange = function() {
            console.log(this.checked);
            if (this.checked){
                console.log(this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.firstChild.nodeValue.trim());
            }
        };
    }
}​
```

Comment: I feel such a fool...so, inappropriately caching ones variables is...not always a great idea, then. Oops. Thank you! =)

Answer (score 2):

Isn't `that` always the last row e.g. try `console.log(that, that.checked)` , wrap it in a closure see your edited [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z88HH/8/)

```
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {

    if (c[i].type == 'checkbox') {
        c[i].onchange = function(){ 
            var that = c[i];                    
            return function() {
            console.log(that, that.checked);
            if (that.checked){
                console.log(that.parentNode.nextElementSibling.firstChild.nodeValue.trim());
            }
    }}();
    }
}​
```